# In an R dataframe, how do I broadcast columns corresponding to dimensions?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, aggregate

I have an R dataframe:

```
# here just define it directly, but it comes from a simulation
simPrice <- data.frame(simId=c(1,1,2,2), 
                       crop=rep(c('apple','pear'),2), 
                       mean=rep(c(10,22),2), 
                       sd=rep(c(2,4),2), 
                       price=c(9,21,12,18))

    simId   crop mean sd price
  1     1  apple   10  2     9
  2     1   pear   22  4    21
  3     2  apple   10  2    12
  4     2   pear   22  4    18
```

This is the price of fruit (apples and pears) in two different iterations of a simulation.  In general, I may have any number of fruit or iterations.  Crucially, I may also have other columns (e.g. varieties, date sold, location sold, etc).

I have another dataframe giving the volume of fruit grown at a number of farms:

```
# here just define it directly, but it comes from a simulation
simVol  <- data.frame(simId=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                      farm=rep(c('farm A', 'farm A', 'farm B', 'farm B'),2),
                      crop=rep(c('apple','pear'),4), 
                      mean=rep(c(10,22),4), 
                      sd=rep(c(2,4),4), 
                      volume=c(9,21,12,18,10,22,11,19))

  simId   farm  crop mean sd volume
1     1 farm A apple   10  2      9
2     1 farm A  pear   22  4     21
3     1 farm B apple   10  2     12
4     1 farm B  pear   22  4     18
5     2 farm A apple   10  2     10
6     2 farm A  pear   22  4     22
7     2 farm B apple   10  2     11
8     2 farm B  pear   22  4     19
```

Now I want to multiply these together.

I assume that to do this, I have to first "broadcast" `simPrice` over `farm`s so that the two dataframes have exactly the same order.

My solution is this:

```
broadcast <- function(origDf, broadcast_dimList) {
    newDimDf <- do.call(expand.grid, broadcast_dimList);
    nReps <- nrow(newDimDf);
    # replicate each line of the original dataframe in place
    result <- origDf[sort(rep(row.names(origDf), nReps)), 1:ncol(origDf)]
    # add the new dimensions, repeated for each simId
    result <- cbind(newDimDf, result);
    # rename rows sequentially
    row.names(result)<-NULL; 
    return(result);
}

bcastSimPrice <- broadcast(simPrice, list(farm=c('farm A','farm B')))

    farm simId  crop mean sd price
1 farm A     1 apple   10  2     9
2 farm B     1 apple   10  2     9
3 farm A     1  pear   22  4    21
4 farm B     1  pear   22  4    21
5 farm A     2 apple   10  2    12
6 farm B     2 apple   10  2    12
7 farm A     2  pear   22  4    18
8 farm B     2  pear   22  4    18
```

This works, but it leaves me with the problem of now trying to match up the rows of `bcastSimPrice` (farms incrementing before crops) with the rows of `simVol` (the other way around).

Is there another way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "multiply these together". What do you hope to multiply with what?

Comment: I want to multiply the price by the volume, row by row, so that I have the revenue of each crop at each farm in each iteration of the simulation. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, ok. I was confused because that is not show in what you have called `result`. Have you tried `merge(simVol, simPrice)` to get to your intermediate stage?

Comment: Ah, `merge` looks like what I need - thanks! (BTW, good point - I've renamed `result` in the question now).

Comment: I don't see any multiplication here, perhaps you're not showing us your expected end result?

Comment: +1 for making a small, easily reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` will do what you intend your `broadcast` function to do.

A simple:

```
bcastSimPrice <- within(merge(simPrice, simVol), revenue <- volume * price)
```

should do the trick. Here I've wrapped merge in `within` to also add the column giving the revenue (`volume` x `price`).

Then, if you need to group rows (e.g. if there are multiple instances of farm A for a given crop and simId), then you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(revenue ~ simId + crop + farm, sum, data=bcastSimPrice)
```

Comment: That's excellent - thanks! And thanks also for the pointer to `aggregate` - you read my mind.

Comment: No problem - it seemed the logical next step :)

Comment: BTW, I generated the simulation data using the procedure I outline in this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490788/how-to-structure-an-easily-extensible-monte-carlo-model-in-r/#answer-21574888 . If you have any comments on that I'd appreciate them too!

Answer (score 4):

Here's solution with dplyr. First we set up the data (I assumed including sd and mean in your volume data was an error)

```
simPrice <- data.frame(
  simId = c(1, 1, 2, 2),  
  crop = rep(c('apple', 'pear'), 2),  
  mean = rep(c(10, 22), 2),  
  sd = rep(c(2, 4), 2),  
  price = c(9, 21, 12, 18),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

simVol  <- data.frame(
  simId = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),  
  farm = rep(c('farm A', 'farm A', 'farm B', 'farm B'), 2), 
  crop = rep(c('apple', 'pear'), 4),  
  volume = c(9, 21, 12, 18, 10, 22, 11, 19),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Next we join the two datasets together (join is a slightly more common description for this task than merge). Here I'm using a `left_join()` which always preserves all rows on the left. `mutate()` adds new columns, and `%.%` strings the operations together.

```
library(dplyr)

rev <- simPrice %.% 
  left_join(simVol, by = c("simId", "crop")) %.%
  mutate(revenue = volume * price)
rev
```

You can also group and aggregate

```
rev %.%
  group_by(simId, crop, farm) %.%
  summarise(revenue = sum(revenue))
```

You might find dplyr useful because it names the most common data analysis operations. The [introductory vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) gives more details.

Comment: Thanks! What are the pros and cons of dplyr's left_join, mutate, group_by and summarise vs. R's merge, within and aggregate?

Comment: @RacingTadpole they usually at least an order of magnitude faster, have consistent arguments (so are easier to learn) and avoid making copies of your data wherever possible.

Comment: I see I can use `left_join` without a `by` argument to join on all common columns.  However, it gives me a warning when I do this - `Joining by: c('farms', 'crops')`. Is there a way to suppress or silence these warnings (and only these ones)?

Comment: @RacingTadpole yes, supply the variable names ;) (and it's not a warning, it's just a message)

Comment: When I type your code above in, for the final `summarise` statement, the output is a single line: revenue 1998. I get the same even if I change the `group_by` to `group_by(simId, farm)` (ie. leave out `crop`). How do I get a summary of revenue by farm?  Thanks!

Comment: @RacingTadpole the code works for me as is when copy and pasted. Maybe you have an old version of dplyr?

Comment: That must have been it - I just did `install.packages("dplyr")`, got version 0.1.1, and it works. Thanks.